# AttributeError: 'DagModel' object has no attribute 'create_dagrun'. Having this error after migration from airflow 1 to airflow 2

Tags: python, airflow

I migrated a dag from airflow 1.10.12 to airflow 2.2.4. The dag was running properly with airflow 1 but I am having this error with airflow 2. Do you please have an idea where this can come from? Thanks

```
AttributeError: 'DagModel' object has no attribute 'create_dagrun'
[2022-07-19, 09:55:13 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1272} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=backfill.scheduler, task_id=schedule_runners, execution_date=20220719T095000, start_date=20220719T095512, end_date=20220719T095513
[2022-07-19, 09:55:13 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:89} ERROR - Failed to execute job 76 for task schedule_runners
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/task/task_runner/standard_task_runner.py", line 85, in _start_by_fork
    args.func(args, dag=self.dag)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 48, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 92, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 298, in task_run
    _run_task_by_selected_method(args, dag, ti)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 107, in _run_task_by_selected_method
    _run_raw_task(args, ti)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 180, in _run_raw_task
    ti._run_raw_task(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1334, in _run_raw_task
    self._execute_task_with_callbacks(context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1460, in _execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, self.task)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1516, in _execute_task
    result = execute_callable(context=context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 174, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 188, in execute_callable
```

Comment: Did the other DAGs run successfully? I doubt the issue is in this DAG. It is more of like the migrations.

Comment: If you can provide the DAG code, maybe we will have a better chance to help.

Comment: Maybe these two codes may clarify more:

backfill_runner = (
        session.query(DagModel)
        .filter(DagModel.dag_id == "backfill.runner")
        .first()
    )
    if not backfill_runner:
        raise AirflowException(
            "backfill.runner is not available in the current dagbag"
        )

backfill_runner.create_dagrun(
            run_id=f"scheduled__backfill_{dag_id}"
            + datetime.now().isoformat(),
            execution_date=None,
            state=State.RUNNING,
            conf=runner_conf,
        )

Comment: The issue is happening with the create_dagrun.

Yes other dags are running correctly.